# KNN imputation for categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have categorical data, preview of which is shown below:

```
0       Laborers
1     Core staff
2       Laborers
3       Laborers
4     Core staff
5       Laborers
6    Accountants
7       Managers
8            NaN
9       Laborers
...up to 307511 rows
```

I want to impute null, nan values (there are approx 9000 missing values) using KNN method, I am using Sklearn for this but I am unable to, is there any other method to do this?

And I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

X = [data['column_name']]
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
imputer.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: can you share your full trace back error?

Comment: I am getting this error Memory error:

Comment: @AftabuddinRasool Memory error means your data is too large that it does not fit in the RAM, also why are you transforming data using just 1 column, aren't you supposed to pass all the features?